# Getting error while compiling my autosave work

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim BackupFolderPath As String



BackupFolderPath = "C:\Users\asespinosa\Documents\Asset Management Files\For Test\Save"

Call Save_Backup("C:\Users\asespinosa\Documents\Asset Management Files\For Test\Save")

End Sub


Private Sub Save_Backup(ByVal "C:\Users\asespinosa\Documents\Asset Management Files\For Test\Save\" As String)



Dim fso As Object
Dim ExtensionName As String, Filename As String
Dim wbSource As Workbook


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook


ExtensionName = fso.GetExtensionName(wbSource.Name)
Filename = Replace(wbSource.Name, "." & ExtensionName, "")


fso.Copyfile ThisWorkbook.FullName,..
 fso.BuildPath(C:\Users\asespinosa\Documents\Asset Management Files\For Test\Save, Filename &"("&Format(Now(),"mm-dd-yy hhmmss AM/PM")&")."&ExtensionName)
 

Set fso = Nothing
Set wbSource = Nothing


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You probably mean: `Private Sub Save_Backup(Optional ByVal sFilename As String = "C:\Users\asespinosa\Documents\Asset Management Files\For Test\Save\")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom Workbook Backup

- The `Save_Backup` procedure could be copied to a standard module.

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Const BackupFolderPath  As String = "C:\Users\asespinosa\Documents\" _
        & "Asset Management Files\For Test\Save"

    Save_Backup Me, BackupFolderPath
    
    ' Open file location in Windows Explorer:
    'Me.FollowHyperlink BackupFolderPath

End Sub

Sub Save_Backup( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal BackupFolderPath As String)
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim OldPath As String: OldPath = wb.FullName
        Dim fName As String: fName = wb.Name
        Dim fBase As String: fBase = .GetBaseName(fName)
        Dim fExt As String: fExt = .GetExtensionName(fName)
        Dim NewName As String: NewName = fBase & "(" _
            & Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yy hhmmss AM/PM") & ")." & fExt
        Dim NewPath As String: NewPath = .BuildPath(BackupFolderPath, NewName)
        .Copyfile OldPath, NewPath
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    MsgBox "No backup created.", vbCritical, "Backup Error"
    Resume ProcExit
    
End Sub
```